# How do I get CGIHTTPServer to ask for user/pass

Tags: python, simplehttpserver

I just want to start a CGI HTTP Server in Python, that asks for user/pass. How can I do this?

The HTTP Basic authentication (with a browser popup box that asks for name/password) will be fine (and probably preferred).

Comment: are you sure that's all you want?  You could serve static html just for the "asking" for a password.  Here, i'll do it right now, "What's your password?"  do you maybe want to do something with the password?  what's the problem you are really trying to solve?

Comment: Do you want to use HTTP Basic authentication (with a browser popup box that asks for name/password), or do you want an HTML login form with your own code?

Comment: @Greg Hewgill: HTTP Basic Authentication will do.

Answer (score 1):

Returning a status code of 401 and a `WWW-Authenticate` header will tell the browser to prompt the user for credentials. See [RFC 2617](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2617.txt) for details.

Comment: How do I do this simply with "CGIHTTPServer" (I've seen one liners to start webservers, so surely I don't need to reimplement the RFC for authentication).

Comment: @Clinton: If you're doing CGI, then the web server is not involved (it just passes HTTP headers between your CGI and the browser). So, return a 401 status code with a `WWW-Authenticate` header from your CGI program.